# Getting x, y coordinate for objects in an array

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have a UIImageView object that i'm trying to get x coordinate of.  I do this with code below

```
endingPoint.x = myObject.center.x;
```

Now, how can i do this if i have the same UIImageView inside of an array that i'm trying to loop through and get each object's x coordinate, some thing like below?

```
endingPoint.x = [posArray objectAtIndex:i].center.x;
```

I know it's a newbie question but i'm just starting with iOS.

Comment: The best way is "test by yourself". For a newbie the best thing is practicing, check by do some coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. *objectAtIndex:* however, returns objects of type *id* (a generic pointer to anything), so you may not call *.center* (property) on it.

You must send it a message using the brackets symbols like this:

```
endingPoint.x = [[posArray objectAtIndex:i] center].x;
```

or *cast* the value to (UIImageView *) first:

```
endingPoint.x = ((UIImageView *)[posArray objectAtIndex:i]).center.x;
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be done inside a for loop obviously.
You can do it either in an Objective-C fast enumeration loop or in a standard for loop.

Fast enumeration loop would look something like this.

```
for (UIImageView *image in posArray) {
    endingPoint.x = image.center.x;
    // Do everything else you want to do with the UIImageView inside the array.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This inside a loop should work:

```
endingPoint.x = [[posArray objectAtIndex:i] center].x;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
endingPoint.x = [[posArray objectAtIndex:i] center].x;
```

or

```
endingPoint.x = ((UIImageView *)[posArray objectAtIndex:i]).center.x;
```

Comment: thanks guys, all those parenthesis and square brackets are so confusing to a newbie :(